# How to save wtime differences in a File from multiple thread in OpenMP?

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to use OpenMP for a database internal project to improve performance. I need the running time(am using `omp_get_wtime()`) to be saved in file as there is no way I can print anything to console from this program. Please suggest if any better way exists. I tried to write to a single file from all the threads(see below code), but that is crashing when number of threads are more than one. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  fp = fopen("/home/fopen.txt","a");
  ...
  omp_set_num_threads(2);
  fprintf(fp,"Num of threads: %d\n",omp_get_num_threads());


#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(tid)
  {
      tid = omp_get_thread_num();

      #pragma omp critical
      fprintf(fp,"ThreadID of this thread is %d\n",tid);
      :
      :
  }
  if (fp != NULL)
  fclose(fp);
```

Comment: Set up an array for recording times, have each thread write to an element of the array (indexed by thread number).  After the parallel region have the remaining active thread write the array to file.  If you do manage to sort out parallel writing to a single file, you'll only end up back here complaining that the writes are not ordered as you want them ...

Comment: Thanks. Seems this approach is working for me.

Comment: Why don't you write up the answer to your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to set up an array for recording times, had each thread write to an element of the array (indexed by thread number). After the parallel region had the remaining active thread write the array to file. Thanks to @High Performance Mark.